# Why cant I see my custom payment gateway plugin as a payment option, on the checkout page of my WordPress WooCommerce Store?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, woocommerce-blocks

I am trying to create a new custom payment gateway which should be fairly simple, but even having stripped back the entire plugin I am still unable to get my payment option to appear as an option on the checkout page.

This is the error that I get every time I try to test either my gateway or another custom gateway from the internet. I have found various very simple implementations, and none of them work.

[No payment methods available error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYyV7.png)

Here I am testing using the [WooCommerce Offline Gateway by SkyVerge](https://github.com/bekarice/woocommerce-gateway-offline) that is a simple copy of the existing cheque gateway that comes with the WooCommerce plugin.

[WordPress Plugins Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDNlS.png)

You can also see here that I have enabled the payment method from WooCommerce plugin
settings

[WooCommerce Payment Methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cQfN.png)

Once this is enabled, WooCommerce also stops showing a notification that it does not have a payment gateway enabled, but all the same once you get to the checkout page, it stops working.

I have had a friend who has an existing WooCommerce Site test this simple plugin, and they are able to use the simple WooCommerce Offline Gateway and others as intended.

My site is the latest WordPress Image, and I have tried hosting it locally a couple of different ways to see if that helps using both Docker and WAMP, I am only adding the bare minimum information on the site, I am not changing any settings or doing any extra configuration. I am simply installing WooCommerce, Adding a single product and adding my payment gateway.

I have read the latest documentation and browsed many extensions but there doesn't seem to be much variation between these simple custom gateways, and they should be quite simple to see work for testing purposes, ultimately this is blocking me as I am unable to test a create a payment gateway of my own if I am unable to see or test it.

Comment: There's a "Manage" button next to the "Offline" payment gateway, what's behind that? Any additional options in there perhaps, which would make the gateway not _applicable_ for the current user, or whatever specific products they are trying to order?

Comment: You can't see your payment method as you are using Checkout Blocks and not Classic Checkout. For Checkout Blocks custom payment method, see those threads/tutorials: https://www.google.com/search?q=WooCommerce+Checkout+Blocks+custom+payment+method

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I think you are correct, we just found https://wordpress.org/support/topic/payment-gateway-bug-urgent-version-8-3-1/

Which gives a similar explanation, It seems as a new wordpress user it defaults your checkout to this version and there seems to be some sort of bug around updating the checkout currently. You end up in a loop. The fix for now seems to be running an older version of wordpress, 6.3 does the job, this adds the old checkout.